# Communications level is not appearing?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

After building 4 Imperial levels, Darth Vader asks me to build a communications level. I have built 3 more Imperial levels (Extending Bridge, Turbolaser, and Detention Level), but the Communications level isn't appearing. How can I get the Communications level to appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you build any level type (Imperial, residential, service, Recreational, etc) the actual result is **random**.  The only way to specify the specific floor to build is to purchase it with Bux.

[image]

Other users have experienced the same results as in this [instance it took one user 12 imperial floors to get the communications level.](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=206616&page=30)

Comment: When you build any level type (Imperial, residential, service, Recreational, etc) the actual result is **random**. The only way to specify the specific floor to build is to purchase it with Bux. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBpik.png) Other users have experienced the same results as in this [instance it took one user 12 imperial floors to get the communications level.](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=206616&page=30)

Comment: I'm not sure it's random for Imperial levels..
I got the same set of floors as OP so far (Extended Bridge and Turbolaser). I'm just trying to get Communications to keep the missions going but it looks like I'm just gonna have to skip it with Bux...

Comment: I really don't think it's true that Imperial levels are random I've played through the game twice, and each time the Imperial levels showed up in the same order as I bought them.

Comment: It took me 9 imperial levels to get the communication level on my windows 8.1 playing.

Comment: @Jiggily  I did not get the same imperial levels as OP & as a few of my friends.

Comment: For those thinking about using bucks...I mean that's fine, but realize that there are only 5-6 vader missions total after that point, so hurrying may only have limited value.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to guarantee which floor you are going to get is by using Imperial Bux and buying it from the Levels section in the menu.  On mine(not sure if changes with the number of floors you have) it costs 97 Bux.

Other than that I believe the Imperial floors are random like the rest of the business floors.

Comment: The amount of bux it costs to buy a specific level increases with every level built. So buying the communication level early is best, if you are going with the buying route. If you are patient, you can just build keep building Imperial levels until you eventually get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you click "build new level" and choose the option "build specific level" it is possible to buy a communication level for just one bux plus the amount of coins you normally pay for a level. If you want to save up bux, that's cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, it's random which Imperial floor you'll receive.  My guess is this is a bug, as previously, when a mission prompts you to build a floor, it is automatically the next floor you build.

I would advise anyone who is stuck on their first "build communications" mission to pay Vader the 2-3 Bux to skip the mission.  The rewards for imperial levels steadily get better, and I have yet to encounter a mission that requires a level to be built since.  It's not worth spending money on supply officers, but having an outlet for the free ones you receive is nice.

Comment: Vader missions run out, and run out fairly quickly actually. Skipping this mission means one less payout. I suspect this mission is meant to teach players how to pick a specific level when building. The developers just decided not to give the player the necessary bux and funds because TDS is very tight with its bux as a way to give players stonger nudges to buy bux and/or to make the existing content last longer.

Comment: @StarPilot The payout isn't totally lost, you still get the coins, but I understand that it's one less payout that your supply officers can earn for you. There are a lot of conflicting reports as to how many Vader missions it is possible to get.  The game has other, more obvious, bugs - so I'm speculating  that Vader not giving you any more missions early is simply another bug.